# Fail whe i try to connect my app to webServices

Tags: java, android, rest, web-services

Actully i working in a app, but i have problems to connect my Web services, i have this code:

```
try{
            HttpServices post = new HttpServices ("http://sotem.com.mx/WebServices/controller.php");
            post.add("funcion", "test");
            System.out.println("Si lo mande///////////////////Jhgfdsa");
            String respuesta = post.getRespueta();
            System.out.println(respuesta);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Cool: "+respuesta, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }catch (Exception ex) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"error: "+ex.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
```

but i can make connection, i try to make other thinks, but i can make the thread, i'am new in this part, the app launcher this error:

android os network on main thread exception

Answer (score 1):

It is not okay to do the Network Operation on main thread.. You can use [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask) to perform such operations and handle the result in `onPostExecute` method.

```
class YourNetworkingTasks extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    try{
        HttpServices post = new HttpServices ("http://sotem.com.mx/WebServices/controller.php");
        post.add("funcion", "test");

        String respuesta = post.getRespueta();
        Log.d("Output", respuesta);
        // DON'T DO ANY UI CHANGES LIKE TOAST FROM BACKGROUND THREAD.. Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Cool: "+respuesta, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }catch (Exception ex) {
       // DON'T DO ANY UI CHANGES LIKE TOAST FROM BACKGROUND THREAD..  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"error: "+ex.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
return null;
}

protected void onPostExecute(RSSFeed feed) {
    // TODO: YOU CAN MAKE U.I. Changes Like Display text in TextView, TOAST HERE.
    // TODO: do something with the result
  }
}
```

And write `new YourNetworkingTasks().execute();` to run that code in background thread.

Please also not that since you are using **http** and not **https** you may get [Network Security Exception](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config) and may not get any output due to recent security change in android.